# Using AuthorizeNet.APICore merchantAuthenticationType class does not have the property transactionkey

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, authorize.net

I am using AuthorizeNet.APICore and after i upgraded my framework from .Net 4.0 to .Net 4.5 i received this error:

> 'AuthorizeNet.APICore.merchantAuthenticationType' does not contain a
>   definition for 'transactionKey' and no extension method
>   'transactionKey' accepting a first argument of type
>   'AuthorizeNet.APICore.merchantAuthenticationType' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is a MVC Razor website application

I am including the references and imports:

```
using System.Xml; 
using System.Xml.Serialization;  
usingAuthorizeNet.APICore;
```

Here `request` is an instance of `ANetApiRequest` and the `transactionkey` property is throwing the error.

```
request.merchantAuthentication = new merchantAuthenticationType();
request.merchantAuthentication.name = ObjModel.APILoginId;
request.merchantAuthentication.transactionKey = ObjModel.TransactionKey;
```

I'm not sure where this error came from or how to fix it. any help?